# How to manage the values that falls in between two ranges in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, range

I've a dataframe `df`:

```
     A  
1   12       
2   15.5
3   20.5
4   30.5
5   15
```

## range:

```
x_range = [list(range(0,5)),list(range(6,10)),list(range(11,15)),list(range(15,20)),list(range(21,25))]
```

## function:

```
def min_max_range(x,y):
    for a in y:
        if int(x) in a:
            min_val = min(a)
            max_val = max(a)+1
            return max_val - min_val
```

The resulant should look like this:

```
df['A'].apply(lambda x: min_max_range(x,x_range))

     A      B
1   12      5 
2   15      5
3   20.5    4
4   5.5     4
5   15.5    4
```

But what i'm getting is this:

```
     A      B
1   12      4 
2   15      5
3   20.5   NA
4   5.5    NA
5   15.5   NA
```

I know why it is happening, its not considering the values between, `range(0,5) = [0,1,2,3,4,5]` and `range(6,10) = [6,7,8,9,10]`, now it's not considering the values `between 5 & 6`. If there's a value `5.5 or 5.8`. then it won't consider it and return`NA`. How can i avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems problem is last value, it is not `5` but `4`, so in ranges last value missing:

```
print (list(range(0,5)))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print (list(range(6,10)))
[6, 7, 8, 9]
print (list(range(11,15)))
[11, 12, 13, 14]
```

I think is necessary add one value to second integers in ranges like:

```
print (list(range(0,6)))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print (list(range(6,11)))
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print (list(range(11,16)))
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

After changed values there is no `NaN`s:

```
x_range = [list(range(0,6)),list(range(6,11)),list(range(11,16)),
           list(range(16,21)),list(range(21,26))]

def min_max_range(x,y):
    for a in y:
        if int(x) in a:
            min_val = min(a)
            max_val = max(a)+1
            return max_val - min_val

df['B'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: min_max_range(x,x_range))
print (df)
      A  B
1  12.0  5
2  15.0  5
3  20.5  6
4   5.5  6
5  15.5  5
```

Comment: But my question is, if range(0,6) will give [0,1,2,3,4,5] and range(6,10)  = [,6,7,8,9]. Now what will happen to the value that are between 5&6 that is "5.1 - 5.9".

Comment: @astroluv Then values between 5&6 matched in `range(0,6)`